# Allow only one more parameter in url after certain string

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create a condition in htaccess to block all urls, if the first parameter matches a string 'abcde' and there are more then 2 parameters after that.
For example

```
example.com/someotherstring/123/more - allowed
example.com/abcde/123 - allowed
example.com/abcde - allowed
example.com/abcde/123/toomany/params - blocked
```

Could anyone kindly advice how to compose such a condition please?
Many thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We are not here to just write code for you - we want to see you make an actual attempt first. You need to go read up on the basics, and then try something. We can help with that then, if you run into problems, provided you give us a proper problem description.

Comment: @CBroe - Very helpful, thanks for your time.